# How to work with SQLite in android

Tags: sqlite

How to work with SQLite in android?

I created EditView for entering name and phone number and three button for "ADD","Delete","Update" operations. Then a ListView in the same activity to populate those data in the list view.

How can I do it in a simple way. I have just started my career so anyone kindly help me.

Comment: *I have just started my career* --> [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) will prove useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite supports all the relational database features. In order to access this database, you don't need to establish any kind of connections for it like JDBC,ODBC e.t.c

Database - Package
The main package is android.database.sqlite that contains the classes to manage your own databases

Database - Creation
In order to create a database you just need to call this method openOrCreateDatabase with your database name and mode as a parameter. It returns an instance of SQLite database which you have to receive in your own object.Its syntax is given below

```
SQLiteDatabse mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("your database name",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

Apart from this , there are other functions available in the database package , that does this job. They are listed below

Sr.No   Method & Description
1

```
openDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
```

This method only opens the existing database with the appropriate flag mode. The common flags mode could be OPEN_READWRITE OPEN_READONLY

2

```
openDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags)
```

It is similar to the above method as it also opens the existing database but it does not define any handler to handle the errors of databases

3

```
openOrCreateDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
```

It not only opens but create the database if it not exists. This method is equivalent to openDatabase method

4

```
openOrCreateDatabase(File file, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
```

This method is similar to above method but it takes the File object as a path rather then a string. It is equivalent to file.getPath()

Database - Insertion
we can create table or insert data into table using execSQL method defined in SQLiteDatabase class. Its syntax is given below

```
mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TutorialsPoint(Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");
mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO TutorialsPoint VALUES('admin','admin');");
```

This will insert some values into our table in our database. Another method that also does the same job but take some additional parameter is given below

Sr.No   Method & Description
1   execSQL(String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
This method not only insert data , but also used to update or modify already existing data in database using bind arguments

Database - Fetching
We can retrieve anything from database using an object of the Cursor class. We will call a method of this class called rawQuery and it will return a resultset with the cursor pointing to the table. We can move the cursor forward and retrieve the data.

```
Cursor resultSet = mydatbase.rawQuery("Select * from TutorialsPoint",null);
resultSet.moveToFirst();
String username = resultSet.getString(1);
String password = resultSet.getString(2);
```

There are other functions available in the Cursor class that allows us to effectively retrieve the data. That includes

Sr.No   Method & Description
1   getColumnCount()This method return the total number of columns of the table.
2   getColumnIndex(String columnName)
This method returns the index number of a column by specifying the name of the column

3   getColumnName(int columnIndex)
This method returns the name of the column by specifying the index of the column

4   getColumnNames()
This method returns the array of all the column names of the table.

5   getCount()
This method returns the total number of rows in the cursor

6   getPosition()
This method returns the current position of the cursor in the table

7   isClosed()
This method returns true if the cursor is closed and return false otherwise

Database - Helper class
For managing all the operations related to the database , an helper class has been given and is called SQLiteOpenHelper. It automatically manages the creation and update of the database. Its syntax is given below

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public DBHelper(){
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
   }
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

[Ref](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1,b2,b3,b4;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    EditText n,i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        n=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        i=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("emp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student1(name VARCHAR, rollno number)");
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student1 VALUES('" + n.getText() + "'," + i.getText() + ");");

            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "hey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                db=openOrCreateDatabase("emp",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student1",null);
                if(c.getCount()==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error no records found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
                while(c.moveToNext())
                {
                    buffer.append("Name : "+c.getString(0)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("RollNo:"+c.getString(1)+"\n");
                }

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, buffer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM student1 WHERE name='" + n.getText().toString() +"';");
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Crash",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                db.execSQL("UPDATE student1 SET name='"+n.getText().toString()+"' where name='heyeee'");
            }
        });



                }


            }
```